# Matlab Co-variance matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics

I have two signals `X : [250x1] double` and `Y : [250x1] double`,

I want to calculate the co-variance matrix, by the [deffinition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix).

The answer should be `C : [250x250] double`. However by `C = cov(X,Y)`,

the answer is `C : [2x2] double`.

What is the problem?

I want to calculate `(X-mean(X))T * C^-1 * (Y-mean(Y))`,

which faces problem with a `C : [2x2] double`.

Comment: well according to your link (last line of the intro): "a 2×2 matrix would be necessary to fully characterize the two-dimensional variation." so everything looks fine no?

Comment: cov(x), if x is a vector, returns the variance of x.

Comment: What does X mean? Is X a multidimensional process or are the rows of X realizations of the same process? (same for Y)

Comment: @Benoit_11, I want to calculate `(X-mean(X))T*C^-1*(Y-mean(Y))`, so `C` should be [250*250] for it to work.

Comment: @NKN, `cov(x,y)` returns the conariance matrix of `x` and `y` according to MATLAB help.

Comment: @gire, `X` and `Y` are two ECG signals, one dimensional [250*1] metric.

Comment: @Kamtal ok could you add this (formatted) information to your question please? Thanks!

Comment: @Kamtal then your covariance will be 2x2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many applications, the concept of covariance is like the variance, but applied to a comparison of two vectors: in place of the sum of squares, we have a sum of cross-products.

According to your comment:

> I want to calculate (X-mean(X))T*C^-1*(Y-mean(Y)),

I guess you are looking for something like the following:

```
X=randn(250,1); 
Y=randn(250,1);
C = (1/249)*(X-mean(X))'*(Y-mean(Y))
```

It has been divided by `N-1` to get an unbiased estimator of the sample covariance.

Also, if you want to comapre two matrices using `cov` function, you may do this:

```
X = randn(250,1);
Y = randn(250,1);
C = cov([X(:) Y(:)])   % the result is  a 2x2 matrix
```

Comment: could you please check [this](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/stat/TR/TR13/TR13-03.pdf) to see that if your formula would work in that pdf eq.(2.4), thanks

Comment: finally I used your formula and it worked, but I'm not sure if it's true!